# Polymer app-header not working as intended without app-header-layout

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Due to stacking context issues with `app-header-layout` I had to remove that component completely and use `<app-header condenses reveals>` by it's own.

My issue is that the header condense, sticky and reveal behaviors are not working as expected and doing weird things.

```
<!-- <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region> -->
<app-header condenses reveals effects="waterfall">
    <div id="pageToolbar">
        <!-- Various global stuff, logo, search, social links -->
    </div>

    <div id="pageHeader" sticky>
        <!--
            Dynamic content that changes based on the page,
            normally contain tabs, and should therefor be sticky
        -->
    </div>
</app-header>

<div id="content">
    <!-- Actual content -->
</div>
<!-- </app-header-layout> -->
```

**Issues**

- The header scrolls out of view way too fast, leaving a visible gap between it and the content.
- Scrolling back up doesn't reveal, until you reach the top; You see the gap again, before the header slides fully into place.
- The sticky element doesn't stick.

All of this worked as expected inside `app-header-layout`.

**App Layout version**

"app-layout": "PolymerElements/app-layout#^0.10.6",

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly because the `<app-header-layout>` element was defining some styles that makes the `<app-toolbar>` work.

Copy the styles defined in the [example linked](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/blob/master/app-header/demo/custom-sticky-element-1.html) and it should work better.

Don't forget to add :

- the `is="custom-style"` attribute in `<style>`,
- the `fixed` attribute in `<app-header>`,
- the `{ padding-top: [your-header-size] }` CSS rule to your `#content` div.

---

```
<style is="custom-style">
body {
  margin: 0;
}
app-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
div#content{
  padding-top: 100px;
}
</style>
```